# PopViewControllerAnimated not working. No ref to calling VC

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a `UITabBarViewController` containing 4 individual ViewControllers. Each VC has a `UIBarButtonItem` on their `NavigationBar` to take you to a "postPage". You get to the post page by using this code, which presents the embedded `NavigationController`

```
- (void)postInvoked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *postPage = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"postPageLead"];
    [self presentViewController:postPage animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in the `PostViewController.m`, I have an `IBAction` that is triggered when the user clicks the `UIBarButtonItem` named "Back":

```
- (IBAction)backOnPost:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This isn't working.. Keep in mind that the calling VC isn't remembered once you arrive at the postpage. How do I traverse back to the original calling `ViewController`?(how do I reference the caller, and is popViewControllerAnimated: necessary?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dismiss it like this instead and it should work fine.

```
- (IBAction)backOnPost:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using:

```
- (IBAction)backOnPost:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: And hows it different from the answer by Dima?

Comment: I just realized it's not. Totally my bad.